# Request to server fails in Firefox when type=submit for button

Tags: javascript, php, html

My html code sends the request to php to send email. In my case the email can be sent in Google Chrome & Edge but not in Firefox when I set the button type=submit, when I change type=button, it works fine. My javascript code is:

```
function Send() {
    var allset = true;
    var namevalid = true;
    var emailvalid = false;
    var commentvalid = false;
    var sent = 0;

    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    if ($("#email").val() == '' || $("#email").val() == null) {
        $("#email").addClass("invalid");
        allset = false;
    }
    else {

        if (!$("#email").val().match(emailPattern)) {
            $("#email").removeClass("valid");
            $("#email").addClass("invalid");
            allset = false;

        }

        else {
            emailvalid = true;
            $("#email").addClass("valid");
        }

    }

    if ($("#comment").val() == '' || $("#comment").val() == null) {
        $("#comment").addClass("invalid");
        allset = false;
    }
    else {
        commentvalid = true;
        $("#comment").addClass("valid");
    }
    $("#name").addClass("valid");

    if (namevalid === true && emailvalid === true && commentvalid === true) {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
        var demo = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
        var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

        alert("Request Successfully Received");


        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xhttp.responseText)
            }
        };
        sent = 1;
        xhttp.open("POST", "email.php?" + "name=" + name + "&mail=" + email + "&phone=" + number + "&msg=" + comment + "&demo=" + demo, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send();

    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please fill all the fields correctly");
    }


}
```

My html for form's button is:

```
 <form class="form" id="form1">

      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
      </p>

      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </p>

        <p class="number">
        <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" class="feedback-input" size="30" id="number" placeholder="Number">
      </p>  

 <p class="number" id="demotype">
        <select class="form-control feedback-input demotype" id="sel1" name="demo">


        <option> something </option>

      </select>
      </p>

      <p class="text">
        <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
          <input type="submit" id="button-blue" onclick="Send()" value="Send" /> 

        <div class="ease"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you saying function Send() is not executed in Firefox? Or that `email.php` is not working as expected? It is not clear from the way you worded your question. You should simplify as much as possible the code posted. Take out any parts not critical to understanding the problem and maybe use a `jsfiddle`. Add 'name='submitbutton' to your submit button. Add `method='POST' to your form. Add 'var_dump($_POST, $_GET)` to your php. Try to  present the problem without the need for an AJAX.

Comment: What's the reason to mix vanilla javascript with jQuery? Why don't you use the jQuery syntax and methods for all the code? It is easiest for you and safely to cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

'type=submit' is basically for submitting forms and 'type=button' is just a button to be bind with some functions. If you don't have any form as its parent element and an error occurs when you click the button, I suggest you to use 'type=button' instead.

Comment: @Marium Malik Then, adding a line with an exception handling to your code might help.

Comment: Where should I add it?

Comment: @Marium Malik Oh, I've just found out something. try replace 'input type' with 'button type'

Comment: @Marium Malik Okay.. I'm out of answers. It will help if you post the whole code or a Fiddle.

Comment: I have added my whole form code as well. There is now just php code that sends mail through mail function, nothing else

Comment: @Marium Malik Okay try this: <form class="form" id="form1" onsubmit="Send()"> and delete onclick="Send()" inside input tag.

Comment: @Marium Malik Have you tried change form method as "post" ? The default value for the form method is "get" and your code seems to be requiring "post".

Comment: If that doesn't work either, I'm sorry I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return false;` at the end of function becuase `submit` button submits your form. Like this.

```
function Send() {
 var allset = true;
            var namevalid = true;
            var emailvalid = false;
            var commentvalid = false;
            var sent=0;

            var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;       




            if ($("#email").val() == '' || $("#email").val() == null) {
                $("#email").addClass("invalid");
                allset = false;
            }
            else {

                if (!$("#email").val().match(emailPattern)) {
                    $("#email").removeClass("valid");
                    $("#email").addClass("invalid");
                    allset = false;

                }

                else {
                    emailvalid = true;
                    $("#email").addClass("valid");
                }

            }

            if ($("#comment").val() == '' || $("#comment").val() == null) {
                $("#comment").addClass("invalid");
                allset = false;
            }
            else {
                commentvalid = true;
                $("#comment").addClass("valid");
            }
         $("#name").addClass("valid");

            if (namevalid === true && emailvalid === true && commentvalid === true) {
               var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
                var demo=document.getElementById("sel1").value;
                var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;                 

alert("Request Successfully Received");


   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
alert(xhttp.responseText)
}
};
sent=1;
xhttp.open("POST", "email.php?"+"name="+name+"&mail="+email+"&phone="+number+"&msg="+comment+"&demo="+demo, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();





}
else
{
    alert("Please fill all the fields correctly");
}

return false;

 }
```

Comment: Still the same, no change